# Add CSS class only to small devices

Tags: materialize

What is the best way to add the class `centered` to all tables in a site styled with [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/) when displayed on a small device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be rule @media can help you. 
[w3school @media](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_example1).